# Windows 10 locks as soon as I log in

Tags: windows-10

Yesterday my Windows 10 machine started experiencing an odd problem. After rebooting it, I have it set to automatically log me in. It's logging in with the only account on the machine, which is an admin account.

However, as soon as I am logged in, the system gets locked, prompting me for my pin. Entering the pin unlocks the system for what feels like a second, and then it goes right back to the lock screen. I can see the desktop loaded during that 1 second, so it almost feels like the lock timeout is set too short. I am able to boot in safe mode with command line, so I do have some abilities. I tried two things so far, and they didn't work.

1. I removed the administrative password from the account.
2. I ran the following two commands to try and increase the timeout
   `powercfg.exe /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_VIDEO VIDEOCONLOCK 60`
   `powercfg.exe /SETACTIVE SCHEME_CURRENT`

This didn't help. I am now no longer prompted for a pin, but the computer still locks instantly.

Comment: If you log into the built-in Administrator does the behavior still exhibit itself?  Edit your question

Comment: Edited. There's just one account, and it'a an admin account which is logging in.

Comment: Doesn’t answer my question.  I know you only have one account.  The built-in Administrator account still exists though but it’s disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound, i misunderstood you. I enabled the "Administrator" account via the command line, and I when I log in using that, it works. So, it does look like the issue is with the user profile.

Comment: Have you tried using the working profile to verify if [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555648) resolution help?

Comment: The values in the registry are already set to what the article is suggesting.

Comment: @PBP - That would indicate you have a different problem.  Are you willing to replace the user profile?  There are tools that can help migrate your user profile data to another user profile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71472/discussion-between-pbg-and-ramhound).